Why does my VSCode always automatically install Chinese Language Pack and how to disable that?
My VSCode always automatically install Chinese Language Pack for me, but I do not need it! Every month I need to mannually uninstall it since I do not want to see it in my extensions (though it does not affect my work). Why it has such behavior and how to disable it?

Wonder if it's something to do with OS/installed language features, spelling atc.

Do you mean changing the system language?

What is it currently? And is Chinese enabled if not the system language?

The system language is Chinese, maybe this is the cause?

I would gamble that this was the reason. I'm a contractor here in the UK and end up using loads of different systems but they are usually set up using American English  which is a little frustrating as dates are always mm/dd/yyyy .  I usually end up adding the UK English and removing the American English language/localalisation.
